# ERROR java.lang.numberformatexception for input string: " "

Tags: java

i cant find out whats wrong with the coding in one of my games
but i know its in this line,

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(spawn[0]), 
     x = Integer.parseInt(spawn[1]), 
     y = Integer.parseInt(spawn[2]), 
     z = Integer.parseInt(spawn[3]), 
     faceDir = Integer.parseInt(spawn[4]);
```

the tabs are supposed to be there.

this might be simple but im kinda new to coding thanks

Comment: Can you give `spawn` values?

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you provided a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that one of the values that you're passing into `parseInt()` is `" "`

Try using a debugger to see what the contents of the `spawn` array is, or you can print the contents to the console/dialog box if you don't want to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Definately spawn[i] it is not integer, thats why are getting this exception

make sure your spawn array should not contains any illegal value, that should not be parsable to integer

for ex: if it contains String "hello" then it should not be parasable to integer, so make sure

Answer (score 0):

One of your spawn[] values is " " which cannot be parsed into a number. To parse a `String` into a number, it has to look like a number; like `"23"` for example.